# Where are the hidden switches?

Tags: achievements, edge

The description for the **Snowblind** achievement in EDGE states that you need to find some switches.

> Find the six hidden switches in the snow-covered levels in December.

Which levels are the snow-covered ones, and where are the switches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2293973) explains it all pretty well.

> Three levels were updated with snow - Normal 1, Bonus 1, and Extended
>   6. Each of these have two hidden switches.

Here are the locations of the switches for Normal 1:

Switch 1
[image: Normal1 first switch]

Switch 2
[image: Normal 1 second switch]

Here are the switch locations for Bonus 1:

Switch 1
[image: bonus 1 switch 1]

Switch 2
[image: bonus 2 switch 2]

Here are the switch locations for Extended 6:

Switch 1 
[image: extended 6 switch 1]

Switch 2
[image: extended 6 switch 2]

Finally, this video shows you where to find them all if the pictures were not clear.